# Inserting data from lists into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using a custom web crawler to pull information from a site (with permission) and storing all of the information into separate lists. I then want to store that information on a table I have created in mysql. I have successfully connected to the DB, and I know that the table name and the places I am INSERT INTO are correct.

Whenever I see examples of inserting data from php it is only showing one or two insertions, but i have 5 lists of info with up to 50 items each. How would I go about inserting the data store in my lists? This is the first program I have ever written in PHP so keep in mind I am not familiar with all the ins and outs of it.

```
<?php
// connect to mysql
include('connect_mysql.php');
// make sure the webservice returns plain text
header( 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' );
// include 3rd party parsing utility
require './vendor/querypath/qp.php';
$gidURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// figure out which guild to scrape info for
// MAKE SURE TO CHANGE TO EXACT URLS ONCE PAGES ARE COMPLETE
if(strpos($gidURL, 'guild_members') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/21284/gid-1-800-druidia/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'liquid-schwartz') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/19528/gid-liquid-schwartz/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'spaceballsdeep') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/14280/gid-spaceballsdeep/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'chapter-eleven') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/41958/gid-chapter-eleven/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'my-own-best-friend') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/4736/gid-my-own-best-friend/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'gone-to-plaid') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/363/gid-gone-to-plaid/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'my-schwartz-is-bigger') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/27827/gid-my-schwartz-is-bigger/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'ludicrousspeed') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/19538/gid-ludicrousspeed/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'lone-starr') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/32650/gid-lone-starr/';
}else {
    echo "No guild was found in the URL.\n";
}

// get the HTML page into the parser
$guild_page = htmlqp( $url );
// $guild_page = htmlqp( './test-druidia.html' ); // for testing if you don't want to hit swgoh.gg
function guild_info_data() {
    // init empty array that will hold our data later
    $guild_members = [];
    global $guild_page;
    // loop through table rows
    foreach ( $guild_page -> find( '.character-list tbody tr' ) as $row ) {
        // init empty array for individual player
        $guild_member = [];
        $member_name = [];
        $member_gp = [];
        $member_cs = [];
        $member_rank = [];
        $member_rank_avg = [];

        // store data in temporary array
        $guild_member[ 'name' ] = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", trim( $row -> branch( 'td' ) -> eq( 0 ) -> text() ) );
        $guild_member[ 'gp' ] = $row -> branch( 'td' ) -> eq( 1 ) -> text();
        $guild_member[ 'collection_score' ] = $row -> branch( 'td' ) -> eq( 2 ) -> text();
        $guild_member[ 'arena_rank' ] = $row -> branch('td') -> eq(3) -> text();
        $guild_member[ 'arena_average' ] = $row -> branch( 'td' ) -> eq( 4 ) -> text();

        // add player array to full response array
        $guild_members[] = $guild_member;
    }

    foreach ($guild_members as $guild_member) {
        $member_name[] = $guild_member['name'];
    }
    foreach ($guild_members as $guild_member) {
        $member_gp[] = $guild_member['gp'];
    }
    foreach ($guild_members as $guild_member) {
        $member_cs[] = $guild_member['collection_score'];
    }
    foreach ($guild_members as $guild_member) {
        $member_rank[] = $guild_member['arena_rank'];
    }
    foreach ($guild_members as $guild_member) {
        $member_rank_avg[] = $guild_member['arena_average'];
    }

}


// check what page is loaded 
if(strpos($gidURL, 'guild_members') !== false) {
    $name_insert = "INSERT INTO gid-1-800-druidia (name, galactic_power, collection_score, arena_rank, arena_average) VALUES ('$member_name', '$member_gp', '$member_cs', '$member_rank', '$member_rank_avg')";

    if(!mysqli_query($dbcon, $name_insert)) {
        die('error inserting new record');
    }else {
        echo 'successfully added info to DB';
    }

}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'liquid-schwartz') !== false) {
    // insert LSD data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'spaceballsdeep') !== false) {
    // insert SBD data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'chapter-eleven') !== false) {
    // insert C11 data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'my-own-best-friend') !== false) {
    // insert MOBF data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'gone-to-plaid') !== false) {
    // insert GtP data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'my-schwartz-is-bigger') !== false) {
    // insert SCH data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'ludicrousspeed') !== false) {
    // insert LS data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'lone-starr') !== false) {
    // insert LST data
}else {
    echo "No guild info was pulled.";
}


// let's get out of here
exit;

?>
```

I was also told that mysqli is better to use so if anyone can go on to explain what is done differently it would also be much appreciated.

```
<?php

// Connect to DB
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'guild_info');

$dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME);

?>
```

Comment: Mysqli is better to use IF, and only IF, used correctly. Parameterize your queries. `gid-1-800-druidia` is an invalid table name if not in backticks. Instead of `error inserting new record` use error reporting, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Comment: Okay thank you! I appreciate the bonus tips as well! I'll add the backticks and see what happens.

Comment: @user3783243 putting the backticks in caused a 500 error.

Comment: Please add the updated code.

Comment: I only added `1-800-Druidia` with the backticks

Comment: Well backticks wouldn't cause a 500 so not sure what to tell you... guess I'll wait for the update.

Comment: @user3783243This worked after using the $dbcon variable. Thanks!

Comment: In that case your developing in an improperly configured environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the variable $dbcon in this line:

```
if(!mysqli_query($dbcon, $name_insert)) {
    die('error inserting new record');
}
```

as well as put the name of the table in backticks like user3783243 such as:

```
$name_insert = "INSERT INTO `gid-1-800-druidia` (name, galactic_power, collection_score, arena_rank, arena_average) VALUES ('$member_name', '$member_gp', '$member_cs', '$member_rank', '$member_rank_avg')";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added mysql connection in connect_mysql.php than you can't access that MYSQL connection variable inside function without passing it as parameter.

So you need to change your code like below,

```
<?php
// connect to mysql
include('connect_mysql.php');
// make sure the webservice returns plain text
header( 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' );
// include 3rd party parsing utility
require './vendor/querypath/qp.php';
$gidURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// figure out which guild to scrape info for
// MAKE SURE TO CHANGE TO EXACT URLS ONCE PAGES ARE COMPLETE
if(strpos($gidURL, 'guild_members') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/21284/gid-1-800-druidia/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'liquid-schwartz') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/19528/gid-liquid-schwartz/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'spaceballsdeep') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/14280/gid-spaceballsdeep/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'chapter-eleven') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/41958/gid-chapter-eleven/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'my-own-best-friend') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/4736/gid-my-own-best-friend/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'gone-to-plaid') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/363/gid-gone-to-plaid/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'my-schwartz-is-bigger') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/27827/gid-my-schwartz-is-bigger/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'ludicrousspeed') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/19538/gid-ludicrousspeed/';
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'lone-starr') !== false) {
    $url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/32650/gid-lone-starr/';
}else {
    echo "No guild was found in the URL.\n";
}

// get the HTML page into the parser
$guild_page = htmlqp( $url );
// $guild_page = htmlqp( './test-druidia.html' ); // for testing if you don't want to hit swgoh.gg
function guild_info_data($dbcon) {
    // init empty array that will hold our data later
    $guild_members = [];
    global $guild_page;
    // loop through table rows
    foreach ( $guild_page -> find( '.character-list tbody tr' ) as $row ) {
        // init empty array for individual player
        $guild_member = [];
        $member_name = [];
        $member_gp = [];
        $member_cs = [];
        $member_rank = [];
        $member_rank_avg = [];

        // store data in temporary array
        $guild_member[ 'name' ] = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", trim( $row -> branch( 'td' ) -> eq( 0 ) -> text() ) );
        $guild_member[ 'gp' ] = $row -> branch( 'td' ) -> eq( 1 ) -> text();
        $guild_member[ 'collection_score' ] = $row -> branch( 'td' ) -> eq( 2 ) -> text();
        $guild_member[ 'arena_rank' ] = $row -> branch('td') -> eq(3) -> text();
        $guild_member[ 'arena_average' ] = $row -> branch( 'td' ) -> eq( 4 ) -> text();

        // add player array to full response array
        $guild_members[] = $guild_member;
    }

    foreach ($guild_members as $guild_member) {
        $member_name[] = $guild_member['name'];
    }
    foreach ($guild_members as $guild_member) {
        $member_gp[] = $guild_member['gp'];
    }
    foreach ($guild_members as $guild_member) {
        $member_cs[] = $guild_member['collection_score'];
    }
    foreach ($guild_members as $guild_member) {
        $member_rank[] = $guild_member['arena_rank'];
    }
    foreach ($guild_members as $guild_member) {
        $member_rank_avg[] = $guild_member['arena_average'];
    }

}


// check what page is loaded 
if(strpos($gidURL, 'guild_members') !== false) {
    $name_insert = "INSERT INTO gid-1-800-druidia (name, galactic_power, collection_score, arena_rank, arena_average) VALUES ('$member_name', '$member_gp', '$member_cs', '$member_rank', '$member_rank_avg')";
 try{
      mysqli_query($dbcon, $name_insert);
 }catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
 }

}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'liquid-schwartz') !== false) {
    // insert LSD data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'spaceballsdeep') !== false) {
    // insert SBD data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'chapter-eleven') !== false) {
    // insert C11 data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'my-own-best-friend') !== false) {
    // insert MOBF data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'gone-to-plaid') !== false) {
    // insert GtP data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'my-schwartz-is-bigger') !== false) {
    // insert SCH data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'ludicrousspeed') !== false) {
    // insert LS data
}else if(strpos($gidURL, 'lone-starr') !== false) {
    // insert LST data
}else {
    echo "No guild info was pulled.";
}


// let's get out of here
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Where did you have declare this $connect_mysql variable

Comment: You have included the connection file but you can't directly use that variable inside function

Comment: If you can attach connection file than i can help you further

Comment: I am not using that variable in the function it would be called within the if statements below the function declaration

Comment: Yup what i am saying is that i am not able to find any declaration of the $connect_mysql variable

Comment: as $connect_mysql this variable should be object of mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

Comment: I have updated my answer please try it it should work

Comment: I now understand what you were trying to tell me, and I updated it with your code and it is still telling me "error inserting new record"

Comment: Okay if you can attach error also so i can help you more on that

Comment: Well its not an error, its just printing out the if statement test telling us that its not connecting: 
if(!mysqli_query($dbcon, $name_insert)) {
        die('error inserting new record');
    }else {
        echo 'successfully added info to DB';
    } <- the die part of this

Comment: Put mysqli_query inside try catch and get the exact error you are facing by catching exception catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {print_r($e)}

Comment: I updated code above. Nothing was caught and it is still just printing 'error inserting new record'. Also want to say thank you for your patience and help. This really has me confused.

Comment: Any luck or are you stumped too? :/

Comment: I have updated code please try this and please give me the exception you are getting

Comment: It is just returning a blank white screen now